# Bind data in json to a select box in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am looking for a way to bind data from a multidimensional array in the scope with my view.

This is the service:

```
sampleApp.factory('ApplicationsService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        save: function () { alert(app_url);
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(app_url+'application-definition/',
             { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': $.session.get("loginToken") } })
                .success(function (data) { if(data.options=="") { 
                alert("No Budget Option.");
                } else {
                $q.applicationOptions = data;
                var arr = $q.applicationOptions.definitions;
                arr.forEach(function(val){ alert(val.name); });
                // $q.options.push.apply($q.options, data.options);
                // $q.services.forEach(function(entry){
                    // alert(entry);
                //});
                deferred.resolve(); } })
                .error(function (err) { alert("error"); deferred.reject(); });
            return deferred.promise; 
        }
    };
});
```

This is the result in the form of json.

```
{
    "definitions": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "technologies": [],
            "expectedTraffic": 0,
            "securityPosture": null,
            "dataSensitivity": "PCI",
            "impactCostDuringHours": 0,
            "impactCostOutsideHours": 0,
            "maximumTolerableOutage": 0,
            "maintenanceWindow": "",
            "_id": "533527b16ce785d6138b524f",
            "organisationId": "532fe5db6ce785ce378b4bb5",
            "created": "Fri, 28 Mar 14 18:41:37 +1100",
            "updated": "Fri, 28 Mar 14 18:41:37 +1100",
            "deleted": false
        },
        {
            "name": "PCII",
            "technologies": [],
            "expectedTraffic": 0,
            "securityPosture": null,
            "dataSensitivity": null,
            "impactCostDuringHours": 0,
            "impactCostOutsideHours": 0,
            "maximumTolerableOutage": 0,
            "maintenanceWindow": "",
            "_id": "53352b5d6ce785d6138b52c6",
            "organisationId": "532fe5db6ce785ce378b4bb5",
            "created": "Fri, 28 Mar 14 18:57:17 +1100",
            "updated": "Fri, 28 Mar 14 18:57:17 +1100",
            "deleted": false
        },
        {
            "name": "PCII",
            "technologies": [],
            "expectedTraffic": 0,
            "securityPosture": null,
            "dataSensitivity": null,
            "impactCostDuringHours": 0,
            "impactCostOutsideHours": 0,
            "maximumTolerableOutage": 0,
            "maintenanceWindow": "",
            "_id": "53354f2e6ce785d6138b53c3",
            "organisationId": "532fe5db6ce785ce378b4bb5",
            "created": "Fri, 28 Mar 14 21:30:06 +1100",
            "updated": "Fri, 28 Mar 14 21:30:06 +1100",
            "deleted": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Test Application Definition 2",
            "technologies": [
                "MySQL",
                "PHP"
            ],
            "expectedTraffic": 1,
            "securityPosture": "Low",
            "dataSensitivity": "PCI",
            "impactCostDuringHours": 1,
            "impactCostOutsideHours": 1,
            "maximumTolerableOutage": 1,
            "maintenanceWindow": "Business or After Hours",
            "_id": "533a8a496ce785ce378b5190",
            "organisationId": "532fe5db6ce785ce378b4bb5",
            "created": "Tue, 01 Apr 14 20:43:37 +1100",
            "updated": "Tue, 01 Apr 14 20:43:37 +1100",
            "deleted": false
        }]
}
```

I want to bind this with a select box. The code I used is:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select-01new" data-ng-options="act in applicationOptions.name">
</select>
```

This is not working. How can I bind data with the select box.

Answer (score 2):

Try `data-ng-options="act.name for act in applicationOptions.definitions"`:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select-01new" data-ng-options="act.name for act in applicationOptions.definitions">
</select>
```

With this binding, we use the `name` property as label and the `whole object` as value

**Update**: Modify your code to assign the json result to your $scope:

```
sampleApp.factory('ApplicationsService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        save: function () { alert(app_url);
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(app_url+'application-definition/',
             { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': $.session.get("loginToken") } })
                .success(function (data) { if(data.options=="") { 
                alert("No Budget Option.");
                } else {

                    deferred.resolve(data); //resolve data
                 } 
               })
                .error(function (err) { alert("error"); deferred.reject(); });
            return deferred.promise; 
        }
    };
});
```

Your controller should do something like this to assign the json:

```
ApplicationsService.save().then(function(data){
     $scope.applicationOptions = data;
});
```

Comment: @Ravneet: what is `$q` in your code? Did you assign it to your $scope?

Comment: this stops all the functionality.

Comment: @Ravneet: how did you call your `ApplicationsService.save()` in your controller?

Comment: I called like this:

`$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { ApplicationsService.save().then( function (data) { $scope.applicationOptions = data.definitions; }, ); });`

Comment: @Ravneet: how about trying `$scope.applicationOptions = data;`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" id="select-01new" 
data-ng-options="definition.name for definition in definitions">
</select>
```